# ensure new mail message defaults to use correct outbound (sender) account

Tags: mail.app

I have two mail accounts in Apple Mail.  Is there a way to ensure that, when making a new message, it is always sent from the correct sender account, based on which mailbox I currently have selected Inbox.  E.g. Imagine I have inboxe with sub-boxes for company_a and company_b.  These correspond to accounts for john@company_a.com and john@company_b.com If I have selected "company_a" I want outbound message to be sent from company_a account with corresponding company_a signature on message.

At moment, Apple mail always defaults to use the first email account defined in accounts list.  I must always click in new message window and change the sender account, which is fine, but I send many messages and it is easy to forget to do it when busy.

If it helps, I also use act-on from SmallCube, but haven't figured out a way to use that to help yet either.

± Rodney

Comment: May I ask what version of Mac OS you're using? I'm currently running Sierra and it's working exactly how you want yours to work without having to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is governed by the Mail Preferences->Composing->Send new messages From setting. The default is 'Account of selected mailbox', which does what you want.